# Sorting pandas dataframe by weekdays

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sorting, dataframe

How do i sort the DataFrame by weekday names? I cannot use pd.to_datetime() method because my dates aren't numbers.

```
    Date    Transactions
0   Friday  140.652174
1   Monday  114.000000
2   Saturday    208.826087
3   Sunday  140.565217
4   Thursday    118.217391
5   Tuesday     107.826087
6   Wednesday   105.608696
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can convert column values to [ordered categoricals](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html), so it is possible to use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
cats = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
df['Date'] = pd.Categorical(df['Date'], categories=cats, ordered=True)
df = df.sort_values('Date')
print (df)
        Date  Transactions
1     Monday    114.000000
5    Tuesday    107.826087
6  Wednesday    105.608696
4   Thursday    118.217391
0     Friday    140.652174
2   Saturday    208.826087
3     Sunday    140.565217
```

Or create an index from the `Date` column with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and lastly [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

*Notice:*
*Solution only works if column values are unique*

```
df = df.set_index('Date').reindex(cats).reset_index()
print (df)

        Date  Transactions
0     Monday    114.000000
1    Tuesday    107.826087
2  Wednesday    105.608696
3   Thursday    118.217391
4     Friday    140.652174
5   Saturday    208.826087
6     Sunday    140.565217
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`calendar.day_name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.day_name) with categorical data:

```
from calendar import day_name

df['Date'] = pd.Categorical(df['Date'], categories=day_name, ordered=True)

df = df.sort_values('Date')

print(df)

        Date  Transactions
1     Monday    114.000000
5    Tuesday    107.826087
6  Wednesday    105.608696
4   Thursday    118.217391
0     Friday    140.652174
2   Saturday    208.826087
3     Sunday    140.565217
```

If in your culture Monday is *not* considered the first day of the week, you can rotate your days of the week by *n* days. For example:

```
from collections import deque

days = deque(day_name)
days.rotate(1)

print(days)

deque(['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday',
       'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'])
```

Then feed `categories=days` as an argument to `pd.Categorical`.